# Decode Javascript

Tags: javascript, decode, compression

I have on my webserver an application from where I encoded/compressed the javascript code long ago. The problem is that I don't got the original source anymore, so I need to decode/decompress the one I got on my webserver but I forgot from where I did this.

Hopefully can someone help me with this..
The script: http://niekess.com/Youplayer/player/javascript.js

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Your browser's dev tools will probably have an option called "pretty print"

Comment: "        _0x59fcx29 = prompt('Please enter the password to skip the video..', '');
" ... I smell... bad things forcing users to see videos till they enter a password o.O. Wanna play a game?

Comment: Hehe, that part is only for skipping to the end of video. Mostly added that for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ for such scripts
Here's your script http://pastebin.com/E1CvdXvp

Comment: Thanks, the variables are different but that is no problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
var _0xbf6e=[.....
console.log( _0xbf6e.toSource() ); // you can see the code
```

Comment: Getting an error with this one...
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource'